# getppid equivalent to get child pid

Tags: c, unix

getppid() returns process ID of parent process.

Since any given process can have only one parent at any time.
Return from getppid makes sense.

Is there any equivalent system call to getChildPid?

I am aware that a process can have many children but in my case, I am sure that my process will have only one child at any point of time. So, in my case it does make sense to have a system call like above.

**Edit:** the child is produced by an external library which does not expose the pid returned by `fork()`.

Comment: Why not just save the pids you get from forking new children?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But the point where I need this child Pid is out of the context of where I saved it.

Comment: @Ram: it cannot be a child process if you haven't forked it.

Comment: I did not say that there is no fork..

Comment: The context in which child pid is saved and the context where I need it are completely different.

Comment: What do you mean by a "different context"? Is it an external library, or maybe someone else's code?

Comment: Or lets say, given a pid, is there any API to get children pids.

I know we can do that in 'ps' command but is there any system call that does exactly the same?

Comment: Then I think you'll have to resort to `ps` because I don't think such a call exists.

Comment: If an external library function creates the new process, you might want to read the documentation of the library to see if it's possible to get the pid of the child. Otherwise it won't really be possible (especially if you fork children of your own, how would you know which process is from your own fork, and which one is from the library fork?)

Comment: You could hook `fork()` and in the the hook function call the original and log and store the value returned.

Answer (score 3):

A process can have many children and it doesn't make sense to have a call that would only return one of them. The most widely used mechanism is to save the returned pid from `fork`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I mentioned in my last statement.

Answer (score 1):

Some APIs are broken and don't expose the pid of the child - on MacOS, `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` is an example. It's completely wrong of the API not to give you the child pid, because you have to be able to `waitpid` on it to clean up the zombie!

For these broken APIs, here's a workaround (used for example by Chrome). In pseudocode:

```
pid_t sneakyFork(std::vector<const char*> args) {

  std::vector<const char*> newArgs = makeVect(
    "/usr/bin/perl","-w", "-e", 
    "printf \"%s,%s\\n\", $$, getppid();" 
    "$ENV{PATH} = '/usr/bin:/bin';" 
    "delete @ENV{'IFS', 'CDPATH', 'ENV', 'BASH_ENV'};" 
    "if ($#ARGV >= 0 and $ARGV[0] =~ /^(\\/.*)$/)" 
    "{ $ARGV[0] = $1;" 
    "  for ($i=1; $i <= $#ARGV; $i++)" 
    "  { $ARGV[$i] =~ /^(.*)$/; $ARGV[$i] = $1; }" 
    "  die unless exec { $ARGV[0] } @ARGV; }",
    (char*)0
  );
  newArgs.insert(newArgs.end(), args.begin(), args.end());
  newArgs.push_back(0);

  int pipe = nasty_library_call_with_stdout_inherited(newArgs);

  char buf[1024];
  read(pipe, &buf); // error checking...
  pid_t pid, ppid;
  parseBuf(buf, &pid, &ppid); // strchr for ',' and strtoul
  if (ppid == getpid())
    return pid; // we're the parent, the trick worked
  else
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could maintain the following structure. Now, when you do a fork(), check the return value(PID). If it is non-zero (more than zero),then it is the parent process. Now, copy that process id in the array.

```
typedef struct
{

   char process[128];
   pid_t current_pid;
   pid_t child_pid[127];
   unsigned  int child_pid_index;
}my_pid_record;


  my_pid_record sample;


  if( ( p = fork()) > 0 )
  {
     printf("I am a parent process\r\n");
     sample.current_pid = getpid();
     strcpy(sample.process,argv[0]);
     sample.child_pid[child_pid_index] = p;
     child_pid_index++;
     /** basically write this information on the disk **/
     /** This is your lookup table **/
     fwrite(file, sample....)
     flush();
  }

else

{
    printf("I am child process..\r\n");

    /** whenever you do fork ..do this routine **/



}
```

Do a get() and set() to read from the file. You will be able to retrieve it. It is a nice question in design point of view, perhaps I would have made a wrapper for fork. Instead of calling fork, call my function.

Comment: Writing to disk is ugly and unnecessary. But the idea is sound - he just needs to store his child pids.

Comment: I can't write on RAM. Because this will be in a different process. The other process cannot access this member directly. There should be then IPC, etc. I thought the best way would be to write in a common place. Also,no one will keep doing forking every now and then. It will be done as soon as the box boots-up.

Comment: You can - the parent can always keep track of its children in its own memory.

Comment: Parent created a childA, then childA created another childB, now this childB created another childC. How the childC will inform to Parent now?

Comment: In child process value of P should be 0. so you need to have separate case for P == 0.